# same word with underscore in powershell

Tags: regex, string, powershell

I have 2 expressions separated by an underscore. I can't create a REGEX that allows me to differentiate them.

Example:

```
"S_Macdo" -match "^S(?<NAME>[a-zA-Z]*)"
```

-> Macdo -> OK

```
"S_Macdo_Fries" -match "^S(?<NAME>[a-zA-Z]*)"
```

-> Macdo -> NOK - I need to have Macdo_Fries

Thanks

Comment: Try `^S_(?<NAME>[a-zA-Z_]*)`. Did you remove underscores deliberately?

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks so much ! 
Yes, i remove deliberately the first underscore

Comment: I wonder if something like `"S_Word_MORE".split("_", 2)[1]` is of any help for you. If there is always an underscore, the format is fixed, it might be simpler alternative.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use

```
^S_(?<NAME>[a-zA-Z_]*)
```

See the [online .NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5ES_%28%3F%3CNAME%3E%5Ba-zA-Z_%5D*%29&i=S_Macdo%0D%0AS_Macdo_Fries&o=m)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `S_` - a literal substring
- `(?<NAME>[a-zA-Z_]*)` - Group "NAME" that captures  0 or more chars that are either ASCII letters or underscores.

Comment: Thanks for your help and the explication

Comment: With powershells by default [case-insensitive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1) operators `[a-zA-Z_]` is redundant. (+1)

Comment: @LotPings True, it is just a force of habit and to be consistent with other environments. In case one needs to use it in another .NET context.

Comment: I know that you know... it's just to avoid confusion when `[a-z_]`, `[A-Z_]` and `[a-zA-Z_]` all have the same result.